# Rails - Trying to query from a date range...everything from today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, range

I'm trying to figure the best way to query a date range from rails...I looked around on Google but am unsure about how to use this syntax.

I have a Model that has various events and I like to add to my find condition a caveat that should only show events where the field :st_date is today or later, in effect only show me data that is current, nothing that happened before today.

I ran into a problem because I have no end date to stop the query, I want to query everything from today to next month.

I was thinking something like

```
 @events = Event.find(:all, :conditions => ["start_date between ? and ?",
         date.Today, date.next_month.beginning_of_month])
```

but I get the error undefined local variable or method `date'......

Do I need do anything particular to use the Date class?  Or is there something wrong with my query syntax?  I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want Date.today, not date.today.  There's nothing wrong with what you're doing, you're just not referencing the date class properly

Furthermore it would be `Date.today.next_month.beginning_of_month`

Comment: Thanks alot, its the smallest things usually....

Answer (score 15):

I would take it a step further and define a scope in your model for reuse.

```
# rails 3 example:
# app/models/event.rb
scope :upcoming, lambda {
  where("start_date between ? and ?", Date.today, Date.today.next_month.beginning_of_month)
}

# app/controllers/some_controller.rb
@events = Event.upcoming
```

There is also a great Railscasts episode on scopes in Rails 3:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3

Comment: shouldn't your scope include the lambda{} symbol so that that dates are evaluated at the time of usage, rather then when the class is loaded?

Comment: you are correct - thanks craig!

Answer (score 6):

`Event.where(:start_date => Date.today..Date.today.next_month.beginning_of_month)` also works great.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my [*by_star*](http://github.com/radar/by_star) plugin which lets you do things like:

```
Event.by_month(Time.now, :field => "start_date")
```